# GRUB doesn't render correctly in 1920x1080

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 13.10, plymouth

I have put those lines into `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080x32
```

(of course, `update-grub` was done after that)

However, GRUB doesn't look right - it has black margins around, renders noticably slow (takes about 1-2 seconds to fill the screen), and the font looks weird - it feels like it makes 1920x1080 image but tries to fit it into a smaller resolution.

After installing Nvidia proprietary drivers, the problem also applies to plymouth.

If I type `vbeinfo` in GRUB's console, it does list 1920x1080 with 32-bit color mode.

What can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In all of the docs I have seen, the second line is

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=KEEP
```

I'd recommend trying that out.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?